# modify font color for R code in latex document using listings

Tags: r, knitr, listings

I am trying to highlight R code in a Latex document, but I can't seem to change the font colors inside the code box. For instance, I think `commentstyle=\color{red}` should give me red font for the comments, but comments appear in either blue or black (can't quite tell). Also, I think `backgroundcolor=\color{white}` should give me a white background...

I'm using knitr and RStudio to write and compile the pdf. Example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{ %
  language=R,                     
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,       
  numbers=left,                   
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},  
  stepnumber=1,                   
  numbersep=5pt,                  
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},  
  showspaces=false,               
  showstringspaces=false,         
  showtabs=false,                     
  rulecolor=\color{black},        
  tabsize=2,                      
  captionpos=b,                   
  breaklines=true,                
  breakatwhitespace=false,        
  title=\lstname,                 
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},      
  commentstyle=\color{red},   
  stringstyle=\color{green},     
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},         
  morekeywords={*,...}            
} 

\begin{document}

This is my document

<<code>>=
render_listings()
# This is a comment
test <- 1 + 1
@

\end{document}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: it appears that knitr uses [Sweavel.sty](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/SweaveTemplate/Sweavel.sty), which defines its own colour scheme for a new environment `Rinput`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your own [Sweavel.sty](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/misc/Sweavel.sty) in your `texmf` tree, `knitr` will use it (otherwise `knitr` will copy a built-in version), so you are free to modify anything in `Sweavel.sty`.