# \usepackage{Sweavel} produces error: It seems you are using the Sweave-specific syntax

Tags: r, knitr

If I include `\usepackage{Sweavel}` in my `.rnw` file, I get an X11 popup error "It seems you are using the Sweave-specific syntax; you may need Sweave2knitr("IPT-baseline-test.rnw") to convert it to knitr" when I compile in RStudio (Version 0.98.484). The document compiles, but I have to dismiss the error.

(1) Any ideas why \usepackage{Sweavel} triggers the error?

(2) Is there a way to turn off the popup since the document compiles anyway?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] colorspace_1.2-4   dichromat_2.0-0    digest_0.6.3       evaluate_0.5.1    
[5] formatR_0.10       ggplot2_0.9.3.1    grid_3.0.2         gtable_0.1.2      
[9] labeling_0.2       MASS_7.3-29        munsell_0.4.2      plyr_1.8          
[13] proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape2_1.2.2     scales_0.2.3      
[17] stringr_0.6.2      tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: Does it say it's an 'error' or is it only a 'warning'?

Comment: Use `knitr` syntax, not Sweave (and not Sweavel).

Comment: @Dwin: it does not appear in the log as far as I can see...opens X11 and creates a popup message

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: i've used the sweavel package before and never got this message. i have a new machine now, so i am wondering if a setting on my old machine suppressed this popup message.

Comment: Do you want to use knitr or sweave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to `\usepackage{Sweavel}` explicitly, I think -- `knitr` should handle that automatically. If you really want to suppress this false positive , you can rename `Sweavel.sty` to a file name that doesn't start with `Sweave` ... the `which_sweave()` function at https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/de7c65c58acfb1f3f5c0ac2f00b92cd2546be943/R/utils-sweave.R shows you what patterns `knitr` is looking for to detect "old Sweave syntax", specifically in this case the regular expression

```
regexp <- 
   '^\\s*\\\\(usepackage(\\[.*\\])?\\{Sweave|SweaveInput\\{|SweaveOpts\\{)'
```

So changing to `mySweavel.sty` should work ...

```
grepl(regexp,"\\usepackage{Sweave}")  ## TRUE
grepl(regexp,"\\usepackage{Sweavel}")  ## TRUE
grepl(regexp,"\\usepackage{mySweavel}")  ## FALSE
```

My guess is that you have a newer version of `knitr` on your new than on your old machine, and it's trying harder to detect old Sweave syntax.

Comment: That is right. `\usepackage{Sweavel}` and `\usepackage{Sweave}` are not necessary for `knitr`, so a warning is issued just to save a few bytes on earth (they can be safely removed) and a few milliseconds for LaTeX.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. @Yihui, knitr used to incorporate `Sweavel.sty`, correct? I started specifying my own file when I wanted to [modify code highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17509667/841405). Regardless, my takeaway is that I don't need to specify it anymore. If I want to keep it for any reason, I need to change the name.

Comment: I just started getting this message out of the blue.  But when I remove \usepackage{Sweavel} I get Environment knitrout undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the  `Sweave`  tag in the latex document prevented the warnings.  It did not prevent the rendering of the file. Thus, the suggestion made in one of the comments above worked... knit2pdf (in my case) figures it out.  - E